# UIImageView only shows low-quality fullscreen images

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I'm displaying an image in UIImageView as a background image to the app. It's a professional photo taken by getty or shutterstock or something. At first i put in 3 photo sizes. they are as follows:

```
320 x 536
640 x 1136
960 x 1704
```

this results in choppy images. so instead of scaling the 640 x 1136 down to 320 x 568, i actually purchased the sizes so the resolution was maintained and noise was reduced. regardless of what i do, they keep ending up choppy and poor quality. any suggestions as to why this is happening? theyre supposed to be great quality.

the yahoo weather app does it flawlessly. great quality pictures. why is my app having such a problem?

here's the code i use to set the background image.

**PARootViewController** - This is initialization. this class starts all other screens and authentication

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:kPAPreviousBackgroundImageIndex];

NSInteger randomNumber;
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSInteger previousBackgroundIndex = [defaults integerForKey:kPAPreviousBackgroundImageIndex];

do {
    randomNumber = [PAProfileObject getRandomNumberBetween:0 to:[self.backgrounds count]];
} while (randomNumber == previousBackgroundIndex);

NSLog(@"Background image at index: %ld\nNumber of backgrounds: %ld",randomNumber,[self.backgrounds count]-1);

[defaults setInteger:randomNumber forKey:kPAPreviousBackgroundImageIndex];
[defaults synchronize];
```

**PABaseViewController** - Every other view controller inherits from this, so it sets the background for every view controller used

```
self.backgrounds = @[[UIImage imageNamed:@"background-02-i5"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"racing-the-sun"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"background-03-i5"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"background-04-i5"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"background-05-i5"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"background-06-i5"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"background-07-i5"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"background-08-i5"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"background-09-i5"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"background-10-i5"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"background-11-i5"]];

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSInteger backgroundIndex = [defaults integerForKey:kPAPreviousBackgroundImageIndex];

if (backgroundIndex >= [self.backgrounds count])
    backgroundIndex = [self.backgrounds count]-1;

self.backgroundImage = [self.backgrounds objectAtIndex:backgroundIndex];

CGRect screen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
self.backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:screen];
self.backgroundImageView.image = self.backgroundImage;
[self.view insertSubview:self.backgroundImageView belowSubview:self.blurView];
```

**PADashboardViewController** - The main screen. It has a button on top that lets the user switch through backgrounds for testing purposes. For now, i set it to the background im working on specifically

```
- (IBAction)nextBackgroundPressed:(id)sender {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSInteger currentBackground = [defaults integerForKey:kPAPreviousBackgroundImageIndex];

    if (currentBackground < [self.backgrounds count]-1)
        currentBackground++;
    else
        currentBackground = 0;

 // self.backgroundImageView.image = [self.backgrounds objectAtIndex:currentBackground];
    self.backgroundImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background-01-i5"];

    [defaults setInteger:currentBackground forKey:kPAPreviousBackgroundImageIndex];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

theyre good images. high quality, straight from shutterstock. it's not the image that's the problem. it only looks like this when i put it in the app. side-by-side screenshot of the exact same image. one is in-app, one is in OS X image viewer. why is the app so terribly grainy?

[image]

Comment: What are the files called? Are you using an asset catalog? (**use an asset catalog!!**) and can you please show the code you are using to set the image in the image view.

Comment: yes i am using an asset catalog. i'll edit my post to show the code

Comment: Are all the images in one image set? i.e. they should be in the 1x, 2x and 3x parts of a single set.

Comment: yes, they are. i have 1x, 2x and 3x in each image. 320 x 568, 640 x 1136, and 960 x 1704 in each

Comment: Are you setting the content mode of the image view? It's hard to tell why without seeing more of the project.

Comment: Have you tried changing the `contentMode` property of your `UIImageView` ? setting `UIViewContentModeCenter` : image pixels would fit with your screen's pixels, while using `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` : image would be resized

Comment: LOL @Vinzzz great minds think alike :)

Comment: no im not setting the content mode. ill try it. any other suggestions before i come back with a result?

Comment: it isnt improving the quality. i tried multiple content modes, including but not limited to UIViewContentModeAspectFill, UIViewContentModeAspectFit, UIViewContentModeRedraw, and UIViewContentModeScaleToFill

Comment: no other suggestions?

Comment: i added a side-by-side screenshot of the image in question. one is being viewed by OS X Image Viewer, the other is the iOS simulator. why is the simulator so grainy?

Comment: Are your images PNGs ? Are you SURE you don't have different images in XCode project ? (have you tried cleaning your project) Why do you use this `UIScreen` bounds ? you could simply use your viewController's view bounds, or directly init with a UIImage (which you're setting the line after). Have you checked your image scale ? Good luck

Comment: Can you please log & share `UIScreen.mainScreen.scale` and `backgroundImage.scale`?

Comment: im using UIScreen bounds so i can get the screen size and fit the UIImageView to the size of the screen. its the background image. and im not sure how to log in and share those things